# How to store values in react, that are not state changing?

Tags: reactjs

I need to store a value in a react app, but not in state, because it should not rerender the view, e. g. the current pos of a mousemove event.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    window.addEventListener("dragenter", this.dragenterDragleave);
    window.addEventListener("dragleave", this.dragenterDragleave);
,}

    dragenterDragleave: function (e) { .. currentType = e.type // store value
```

Comment: You can store it in `this` which is bind to the component for example this.currentType = e.type

Comment: @jmac in componentDidMount ?

Comment: If you want to do that in componentDidMount it would look like this:

`window.addEventListener("dragenter", (value) => this.dragEnter = value);`

Comment: @jmac, sorry I wanted to know which would be the best method, if I have several vars I want to define, where inside the reacrClass would be right?

Comment: As Ved mentioned below, whenever you need it, but if you're assigning to `this`, make sure you're assigning to the proper `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways.

1 Create a global variable on top:

```
var value = null;

export default class Abc extends React.Component {
  <code goes here>
}
```

2 Inside the `constructor` function or `componentWillMount`, create a variable:

```
this.value = null.
```

Assign value to these variable whenever you want.

Comment: What exactly is the constructor function ?